# MongoDB Node.js geolocation

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was wondering if there are any examples that consist on basic geolocation input and database retrieval of given inputs within a certain area, preferably the user's current location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick overview of geospatial queries in MongoDB:

1. You have to insert location information in your collection via 2D array

   ```
   db.example.insert( {"location": [x,y], "category": "restaurant"})
   ```
2. Set up a geospatial indexes on the collection by indicating the location field with "2d" option.

   ```
   db.example.ensureIndex( { "location" : "2d" } )
   ```

   Now the collection will have an index which all geospatial queries will be done against.
3. To query for locations nearby a point (i.e. the user's current location), use the find() command with `$near` operand on the location field giving the point coordinates (i.e. 100, 100.)

   ```
   db.example.find( { "location": { $near : [100, 100] } } )
   ```
4. To find users current location, you would need higher level application support to get the user's current information.

For more information:

- MongoDB documentation:
  http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing
- The `$near` operator: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_near

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on the answer below, so had to post another answer:

`ensureIndex()` has been replaced with `createIndex()`.

See [the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex).